# Email decryption - How does outlook display a KSP PIN entry dialog for a CAPI key?

Tags: email, encryption, outlook, smime

When attempting to open an encrypted email in outlook it displays the standard CNG (Cryptography next generation) Key Storage Provider PIN entry dialog even though the email was encrypted using a CAPI (CryptoApi ) key.

When i attempt to decrypt the same email using a third party library (redemption.dll, An Outlook Object Model replacement) on the same environment an  older CAPI PIN entry dialog is displayed.

[image: CAPI Pin entry dialog][image: CNG Pin entry dialog]

Please could someone explain how outlook is able to use the new CNG PIN entry dialog for a CAPI key as we are looking to implement a solution that uses the new dialog in our product.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure what's your question if you described everything correctly. I just rephrase your description ...

Outlook uses [CNG ( Cryptography API: Next Generation)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa376214(v=vs.85).aspx) and you get you "modern" looking dialog when trying to decrypt the message / accessing private key with [BCryptDecrypt function](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa375391(v=vs.85).aspx).

3rd party library (redemption.dll) probably uses [Microsoft Cryptography API](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa380256(v=vs.85).aspx) when decrypting SMIME message / accessing key with [CryptMsgControl function (CMSG_CTRL_DECRYPT parameter)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa380220(v=vs.85).aspx) and you see the old style dialog.

If you are trying to implement solution yourself, use CNG library and you'll get new style dialogs. You can read more on different providers implementations in this blog post: [What is a strong key protection in Windows?](https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/pki/2009/06/16/what-is-a-strong-key-protection-in-windows/)

Comment: I thought that CNG has it's own set of key storage providers and that each key was only compatible with one API?

Comment: Both APIs have ability to work with Windows key store. In fact this is not requirements at all. You may keep your keys on the file system (for example p12 container) or your custom storage and supply into the functions as you need. Bottom line; keys are the keys, store is the store and crypto API is just API providing crypto functionality. Of cause, Windows crypto API has convenient functions to work with Windows key store, but you may replace any piece with your own, for example use OpenSSL for cryptography. Hope this clarify.

Comment: Excuse my late reply but thanks for this. Clarified very much so.